# Form input shows only borders, they don't focus nor show placeholder html&css

Tags: html, css

I've been on checking on google still cant find solution for my problem.. whereby my form doesn't work input fields do not respon onfocus, also they don't show placeholders nor value. I'll appreciate if someone can show me the problem if it's my code themselves.

```css
#searchForm {
   display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
    border-top: 0.3px solid white;
}

#searchForm form {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

#searchForm form input[type=text] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#searchForm form input[type=submit] {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font size: 16px;
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchForm">
    <form action="header.php" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="que" placeholder="Enter your query and search.." required autofocus />
     <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, your code seems to be showing the inputs text and placeholder

Comment: Thank u all for your concern.. I've discovered that I had set font-size:0; in the parent element.